# OSX Lion and Movist: playback freezes at specific instant

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging, instruments, osx-lion

I'm a newbie developer who worked on [Movist](http://code.google.com/p/movist/) media player over the last months.

The project seems to be dead so I started to look at the code and try to understand how it behaves.

I have been able to add hardware decoding (with VDADecoder), fix all deprecated functions, plus other minor things and everything seems to work nicely on Snow Leopard.

When testing the app on OSX Lion, instead, I encounter a very annoying issue and I'm short of idea because I tried quite everything..

The video playback freezes for about 0.1 - 0.2 seconds always at the same instant during the playback. It seems to freeze just when the decoder reaches the end of file and when the remaining (already) decoded frames get displayed.
The issue appears with both hardware and software decoding and it's not related to the part of code that I have added.

Obviously, the same movie file plays smoothly on Snow Leopard (with both software and hardware decoding) and on Leopard (with software decoding) (hardware decoding isn't supported).

I tried to use Instruments to debug this issue but I don't know how to catch that instant. Sometimes Instruments records a lot of "sys enter trap" around that instant..is this a hint?

I tried to rebuild the project with Xcode 4 and SDK 10.7 and to fix all the warnings but the issue still persists.

Is there a way to debug this issue?
I don't know how to discover the bug...if there is any..

I hope you can help me.

Regards

Andrea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to let everyone know, I found what was causing the issue.
It was given by the `Restorable` feature of the movie window which was causing that periodical stuttering.